# Using a form to populate a database and land on a page with the information submitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, controller

I have a form on my new view that takes in "url" and "title". When I submit my "url" & "title" I am taken to a blank create view. Ideally I would like to populate my database and land on a page that shows the title and link for that project.

This is my controller as it stands:

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def new
    @link = Link.new
  end

  def create

  end

end
```

And this is the form:

```
<h1> This is New page for links </h1>


    <%= form_for(@link) do |f| %>
  <% if @link.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@link.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this link from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @link.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :url %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :url %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

How would I go about creating my methods(actions) to populate the database and then render what I am seeking? Ideally I'd like to see the flow behind how to think about the problem and the final code so that I can reverse engineer it.As long as I see it once I should be able to do it on my own next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to do this

```
def create
  @link = Link.new(params[:link])
  if @link.save
    redirect_to @link
  else
    render :new
  end
end

def show
  @link = Link.find(param[:id])
end
```

In routes.rb you will want to make sure you have the routes for this controller and its actions.

```
resources :links
```

That will provide you the standard `CRUD` HTTP methods with matching routes.

Comment: This almost worked. In addition to this I had to make some private methods for the parameters to pass.

Comment: Oh yea if you are in rails 4 you have to use secure params. It was tagged as rails 3.